# Paper.js onKeyDown method

Tags: javascript, graphics2d, howler.js

I'm quite new to javascript and i'm trying to write a small project-like [Patatap](http://patatap.com/).

I'm using Paper.js for animations and the [onKeyUp method](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/interaction/keyboard-interaction/) for event listener, to make the images appear when I press the buttons. This code works properly, but I don't understand how this method works, **what am I doing under the hood? Am I defining that function again? What am I defining inside the braces?** 
*function onKeyUp(event){ ..defining that function??.. }*

(The same problem I have with the "onFrame ()" method).

```js
//importing paper.js and howler.js
//CREATING AN OBJECT OF LETTERS
 var keyData={
  q: {
    sound: new Howl({
      src: ['sounds/bubbles.mp3']
      }),
    color: '#1abc9c'
    },
  w: {
     sound: new Howl({
       src: ['sounds/clay.mp3']
     }),
     color: '#2ecc71'
   }  //OTHER LETTERS HERE..
 };

//CREATING CIRCLES ON THE SCREEN
  var circles=[];
  function onKeyUp(event) {
    if (keyData[event.key]){
      var maxPoint = new Point(view.size.width,view.size.height);
      var randomPoint = Point.random();
      var point = randomPoint * maxPoint;
      newCircle = new Path.Circle(point, 100);
      newCircle.fillColor=keyData[event.key].color;
      circles.push(newCircle);
      keyData[event.key]['sound'].play()   
    }
  };

//MAKE CIRCLES DISAPPEAR
 function onFrame(event) {
   for(var i=0; i< circles.length;i++){
   circles[i].fillColor.hue += 1;
 circles[i].scale(0.99);
 if(circles[i].area < 1){
   circles[i].remove();
   circles.splice(i, 1);
   console.log(circles);
 }
   }
 };
```

**strong text**

Thank you AdamW for your answer.

The problem I have is about the line above. It makes no sense for me, it's like I'm doing

```js
// ON PAPER.JS
function onKeyUp(event){
  //do stuff..
};

// ON MY PROJECT
function onKeyUp(event){
  //do other different stuff..
};
```

But this way I will only "clear" the onKeyUp() method written on Paper.js and give priority to my new function called onKeyUp(), simply polymorphism.
So, why do I do that? And the same is for the onFrame() method.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of explanation you are asking for and I'm not familiar with Paper.js.

In general terms the body of the function is wrapped in a conditional

```js
if (keyData[event.key]) {
  // do stuff
}
```

The condition gets the `key` property from the `event` parameter and checks to see if `keyData` has a property with that name. Looking at your code, it seems that this would be a key value of 'q' or 'w'. If it finds that property it does the 'do stuff' section otherwise it skips it.

It looks to me like the 'do stuff' section

1. selects a point for the center of a circle
2. creates a circle at that point with a radius of 100 somethings
3. fills the circle with a color
4. adds the circle to an existing array called 'circles'
5. Selects an entry from 'keyData' , gets its 'sound' property and calls it's 'play' method.  the 'sound' property is a 'Howl' object and I assume howls have a play method.

In short it makes a colored disk and a noise.